# Difference between two dates in days

Tags: android, date, calendar

Why do I get the following outcomes?

```
today        = 2014-01-06
selected_day = 2014-01-06
```

Outcome is 0

```
today        = 2014-01-06
selected_day = 2014-01-07
```

Outcome is 0

```
today        = 2014-01-06
selected_day = 2014-01-08
```

Outcome is 1

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date d1 = df.parse(today);
Date d2 = df.parse(selected_date);
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(d1);
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c2.setTime(d2);
long diff = c1.getTimeInMillis() - c2.getTimeInMillis();
System.out.println(diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
```

Comment: so, now you changed it in your code. wrong was a mistake when copying it to stackoverflow?

Comment: Have you solved your problem? If yes, then please accept the answer to let us know that the problem has been solved, and also to appreciate the answerer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are setting both dates to the same calendar instance

```
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();
c1.setTime(d2); // this is wrong :)
```

change the second c1 to c2 ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can set like this way

```
 cal.set(2008, 8, 1);
```

use like this way

```
long diff = daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime());

public int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
            return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
         }
```

Comment: This would work if there's no *time in the day* involved. And using deprecated method is annoying if your are using an IDE like eclipse.

Comment: No I mean, if theres time specified, like 20 o'clock of 2008-8-11 and 8 o'clock of 2008-8-12, you'd get 0 because the time variance is not a full day.

Comment: getTime() returns millisecond so we can get difference in millisecond. if you don't want to difference in day than you don't need to divide (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) with this.

Comment: I know that :). See my example in my previous comment. I mean that when theres time specified (not just date), using millisecond time variance to get day variance will give you a result that only us programer geeks would find reasonable. The day variance of 20 o'clock on 2008-8-11 and 8 o'clock on 2008-8-12 should be 1 not 0 for most people even the time variance is not a full day. But then, I see that everyone here doesn't care much about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

At first instance I misunderstood exact problem. Now when I am clear on that side I thought of putting some info regarding same.

Getting difference considering Date as parameter .. try like this.

```
public static int getDaysDifference(Date fromDate,Date toDate)
{
if(fromDate==null||toDate==null)
return 0;

return (int)( (toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

Getting difference considering Calendar as parameter .. try like this.

```
public static int getDaysDifference(Calendar calendar1,Calendar calendar2)
{
if(calendar1==null||calendar2==null)
return 0;

return (int)( (calendar2.getTimeInMillis() - calendar1.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
}
```

Simply pass value to it. :)

Now if you need to check difference with some values and U need to put some condition then U may try using CompareTo function for that ..

Fallow undermentioned ..

Define your variables like this ..

```
java.util.Date d1;
java.util.Date d2;
```

Your function like this ..

```
public long compareTo(Date d1, Date d2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return d1.getTime() - d2.getTime();

    }
```

Now when you need to use this .. try like this

```
try{

                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

                        try {
                            d1 = sdf.parse(pDisplayDate.getText().toString());
                            d2 = sdf.parse(current_day_validate);
                        } catch (ParseException e1) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        /*System.out.println("1. " + sdf.format(d1).toUpperCase());
                        System.out.println("2. " + sdf.format(d2).toUpperCase());*/

                        if(compareTo(d1, d2) >= 0){
                            sm = new SessionManagement(getApplicationContext());

                            if (service_recog_id == 1) {
                                request_url = StaticVars.service_url;
                                new BussinessOwnerHttpAsyncTask().execute();
                            } else if (recognition_id == 3) {
                                request_url = StaticVars.business_owner_url;
                                new BussinessOwnerHttpAsyncTask().execute();
                            } else if (recognition_id == 4) {
                                request_url = StaticVars.service_provider_url;
                                new BussinessOwnerHttpAsyncTask().execute();
                            } else if (recognition_id == 6) {
                                request_url = StaticVars.service_category_url;
                                new BussinessOwnerHttpAsyncTask().execute();
                            }
                        }else{
// Your other stuff
}
}catch(Exception e){
// Your exception
}
```

Comment: he wants the difference, and not just to know which is before the other :)

Comment: I would give you a -1 if I could. Read the question.

Comment: Yup .. I tried putting more than that. :) @TwilightSun .. Will appreciate your -1 :)